# Finding self-similar homomorphisms of a FSM transducer

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, automata-theory, regular-language, dfa

Consider a special case of homomorphisms of [FSM transducers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Transducers) (or "generalized sequential machines" in [1]). Let $F$ be a transducer accepting a language $L$, and let $h(x)$ be a homomorphism function which maps from $\Sigma \to \Sigma^*$. (Here, $h(x)$ is extended in the standard way to strings, $h(\epsilon)=\epsilon, h(x c) = h(x) h(c)$, where $x$ is a string and $c$ is a symbol from $\Sigma$.) Let $f(x)$ be the output of $F$ on $x$.

> **Problem:** Given $F$, find a non-trivial $h(x)$ such that for all $x \in L$, $h(f(x))$ = $f(h(x))$.

Call this a *self similar homomorphism* (SSH). Has this been studied anywhere? I'm looking for any (partial) insight, or related or nearby references on the following:

> 1. What is an algorithm for finding an SSH? What is its complexity?
> 2. What are sufficient and/or necessary conditions for a solution?
> 3. Are there any applications?

[1] [Introduction to automata theory, languages, and computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation) / Hopcroft & Ullman

Comment: I am a bit lost. Are you considering deterministic transducers? Transducers usually define relations (or functions in the deterministic case). So I do not understand the sentence "let F be a transducer accepting language L". What is the difference between $f$ and $F$? Finally, could you give a brief indication on the motivation of your problem?

Comment: hi @pin thx for attn, re bkg/one "app" as you know/have pointed out there exists a "collatz" transducer; this construction has the potential for identifying inductive (or even "recurrent/fractal-like") structure in that problem or in a more general way [ie other problems]. transducer is deterministic in this case. transducers have an accept state determining language acceptance hence $L$. $f$ function maps from $\Sigma* \to \Sigma*$ or more specifically $L$ is $f$'s domain. would be happy to discuss/clarify further with anyone in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon)

Comment: full/better wikipedia entry [FSM transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer). $F$ _"transduces a string"_ ($x$) according to $f(x)$

Comment: @vzn: can you give details about "exists a Collatz transducer"? I think that you need at least a *repetition* of tranducers (a single application of a transducer can only strip the leading 0s and calculate 3n+1, but you need to apply it multiple times to "generate" the Collatz sequence)

Comment: hi @marzio, thx for interest, yes its a [surprisingly simple] repetition or "cascade" construction for a single iterate as you describe, see eg [collatz conjecture FSM transducer construction](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123491/collatz-conjecture-finite-state-machine-transducer-construction-origination), again can present much more details in chat for anyone interested

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm a few years late with this answer but here goes:

Every homomorphism $h:\Sigma\rightarrow\Sigma^{*}$ has a corresponding deterministic transducer with a single state $q$ (which is accepting) such that on each transition $\delta(q,\sigma)=q$, the machine outputs $h(\sigma)$. In this case the machine $F$ implements the total function $h:\Sigma^{*}\rightarrow\Sigma^{*}$.

The other direction does not hold since $F$ may define a partial function $f:\Sigma^{*}\rightharpoonup\Sigma^{*}$. While the set of regular languages is closed under homomorphism, a single language is not necessarily closed under an arbitrary homomorphism, so there is no gaurantee that $h(x)\in L$. Additionally the function $f$ should really be defined as taking two arguments $f(x,q)$ since the output is dependent on the combination of symbol and state. As such, I think $F$ must define a homomorphism for there to exist an $h$ such that $h(f(x))=f(h(x))$ holds, in which case $L=\Sigma^{*}$, or $L$ must be closed under both $h$ and $f$. In the latter case $L$ would have to be captured by some regular expression that is a concatention of some number of sub-expressions of the form $e_{1}^{*}\cdot...\cdot e_{n}^{*}$, where each $e$ is either a single symbol or a disjunction or a concatenation of kleene star terms similar to the top level expression, otherwise the language would not be closed under the given functions.